# How to coalesce many pairs of columns by replacing NA values in R?

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe that has a large series of similar columns that contain replicate values, such as below:

```
df <- data.frame(y_1 = c(1, NA, 2, 2),
                 y_2 = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
                 z_1 = c(4, 5, NA, 6),
                 z_2 = c(4, 5, 5, 6))
```

Most of the time, the "_1" and "_2" columns are duplicate values. However, there are cases where "_1" might be NA and "_2" will have a value (and vice versa, but I think only one case needs to be considered). I am trying to come up with a way to replace any NA value in "_1" columns with the appropriate value from the "_2" column. Doing this with one pair of columns seems simple enough:

```
df$y_1[which(is.na(df$y_1)] <- df$y_2[which(is.na(df$y_1)]
```

Or

```
df$y_1 <- ifelse(is.na(df$y_1), df$y_2, df$y_1)
```

I need to do this over a large number of columns. Similar questions I've found accomplish this by creating a new column that is a combination of columns. I need to maintain the structure of this dataframe and cannot do that. So long as all non-NA values exists in the "_1" columns, that should work fine.

Can anyone provide some insight as to how I might be able to accomplish the above? Base R would be preferred but isn't necessary. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When your data are in wide format, it is almost always easier to do these operations in a long format and then pivot back to a wide format:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(rn = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(-rn, 
               names_sep = "_",
               names_to = c("name", ".value")) |>
  mutate(`1` = coalesce(`1`, `2`)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_glue = "{name}_{.value}",
              values_from = c(`1`, `2`),
              id_cols = rn) |>
  select(-rn)
```

**Output**

```
    y_1   z_1   y_2   z_2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4     1     4
2     1     5     1     5
3     2     5     2     5
4     2     6     2     6
```